# The HTTP header line [group Name: XXX-OR-Migration^XXX-OR-Novation] does not conform to RFC 7230 and has been ignored

Tags: apache, tomcat9

Our application was working fine on tomcat 8.5.5.   Recently, we have upgraded to tomcat 9.0.31 and the login now fails with the below error

Message: The HTTP header line [group Name: XXX-OR-Migration^XXX-OR-Novation] does not conform to RFC 7230 and has been ignored.

Description: The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

I have added the below attributes in server.xml under the Connector section and the request still fails:

relaxedPathChars="^:{}[]|""
relaxedQueryChars="[]|{}^:\`"<>""

Answer (score 0):

```
java.net.URLEncoder
URLEncoder.encode(String, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Please escape these characters